# How to get last added user or updated users in keycloak?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I wanted to get the list of users which are added or updated in last 1 day.
I read the documentation of keycloak but didn't find any way to get that list.
Anyone please help me, as I m new to keycloak, I don't know the way how to do it.
Actually I wanted to store the latest updated/added users in my local db and have the custom search on that db.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Keycloak event log for this purpose. Events are stored in the database, and can also be written to the log, etc. You would have to enable event logging in advance, though.

When you turn on event logging for Login events it will give a default list of events that will be stored. I recommend going through the list of the ones that are not stored, to see if there are any other events of interest. If you want to track changes done through the admin GUI / API, also enable capture of admin events. Here, I recommend enabling "include representation", as the events without this are quite rudimentary (for instance, update user events are logged only as UPDATE and nothing about what was updated, with the representation the events will contain the state after the update as well).